# Vee-Validate validateAll() with scope

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vee-validate

I have a scenario where I have sectioned out (scoped) a form so that I can validate small chunks at a time using the following function.

```
validateScope (scope) {
  return this.$validator.validateAll(scope);
}
```

I want to do one final validation of the entire form before I submit it to the server; however, validateAll() doesn't seem to pick up inputs that have been added to a scope. I've also tried just validating each scope and then submit the form if they are ALL valid, but I am not sure how to do that since everything is asynchronous.

```
validateAll () {
   let valid = true;

   // Not sure how to build this function since validateScope is asynchronous
   _.each(this.names, (name, index) => {
     if (this.validateScope(`name-${index}`)) {
       valid = false;
     }
   });

   return valid; // Always returns true even though the _.each should set it to false
}
```

Comment: *"pick up inputs that have been added to a scope."* how are you adding inputs to a scope?

Comment: You're going to need to collect all the promises returned from `validateScope` using something like `Promise.all` and then evaluate whether one of them returned false or not. If you want to set up a working example, it would be easier to generate an answer.

Comment: Where in the code is the asynchronous part?

Comment: @bergi `$validator.validateAll` is a [VeeValidate](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/api.html) library function that returns a promise.

Comment: @Bert Ah, I thought it was the function posted in the second snippet…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, your code will end up looking something like this:

```
validateAll () {
   let valid = true;

   let validations = []
   _.each(this.names, (name, index) => {
     validations.push(this.validateScope('name-' + index))
   });

   return Promise.all(validations)
     // consolidate the results into one Boolean
     .then(results => results.every(r => r))
}
```

Then, of course, you'll have to use `validateAll` as a promise:

```
this.validateAll().then(isValid => {
  if (!isValid) {
    //do whatever you need to do when something failed validation
  } else {
    // do whatever you need to do when everything is valid here
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm.

Comment: Does this work with vee-validator? this.$validator referenced an object from that library

Comment: @Bert why lodash and promises? Isn't ES6 already there with async/await and Array.prototype.map?

Comment: @MatthiasHryniszak the individual asking the question was using underscore. You're right, I could have used async/await.